# android:label problem in AndroidManifest (can't set title)

Tags: android, android-manifest

When I tried to give different titles in `AndroidManifest.xml` for each activity, app shows first title for all children activities instead off given titles. I'm new in coding so sorry for wrong explanation of my problem. The code is as following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.android.miwok">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".NumbersActivity"
                android:label="@string/category_numbers" />
            <activity
                android:name=".FamilyActivity"
                android:label="@string/category_family" />
            <activity
                android:name=".ColorsActivity"
                android:label="@string/category_colors" />
            <activity
                android:name=".PhrasesActivity"
                android:label="@string/category_phrases" />
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

How can I solve it?

Update: to make it more clear I'm adding my MainActivity code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);
        TextView colors = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colors);
        TextView family = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.family);
        TextView phrases = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phrases);

        assert numbers != null;
        numbers.setOnClickListener(this);
        assert colors != null;
        colors.setOnClickListener(this);
        assert family != null;
        family.setOnClickListener(this);
        assert phrases != null;
        phrases.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.numbers:
                Intent numberIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NumbersActivity.class);
                startActivity(numberIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.colors:
                Intent colorsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NumbersActivity.class);
                startActivity(colorsIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.family:
                Intent familyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NumbersActivity.class);
                startActivity(familyIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.phrases:
                Intent phrasesIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NumbersActivity.class);
                startActivity(phrasesIntent);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Second update:
When I copied Intents for each activity, I forgot to change activity names, so problem was ot in title but in opened activity.

Comment: That's probably being override by your Toolbar. Try calling `setTitle(R.string.category_numbers);` in your activity inside the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: I can't edit your question to correct one typo in last sentence (minimum 6 chars to edit), therefore I ask it from you. Please change `ass` -> `as` :D

Answer (score 0):

You can name it in code:
by

> actionbar.setTitle("title here");

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!MyApplication.getInstance().isTablet())
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.settings));

    ....
}
```

Comment: Wanted to make it more clear.
I have one mainActivity with 4 links to new activities,(tutorial lesson from udacity - Miwok app), So when I try to give different titles to children activities, second trird and fourth activity just show firts activity's title. When I delete first child activity title, All of them show parent title. This is my MainActivity code:

Comment: Just try to write 'getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your name HERE");' in on create method, it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

So when I copied MainActivity.java from course example, all titles start working normally. The difference is that I used 'switch (view.getId())' instead of creating new onClick for each activity. I still didn't understand why it doesn't work, but hope I will learn it with more experience.
Summary:
Using 'switch' statement for activities can cause problems (for ones without knowledge,like me) in children activities titles.